# Why c++ char array size is increase by one

Tags: c++, arrays

I declare C++ array as follows. Array size is 5 and number of characters are 5. But i have error: `initializer-string for array of chars is too long` When i change array size to 6 or empty, then no error. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char name[5] = "ABCDE";
   cout<<name;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"ABCDE"` is actually 6 characters long. A string terminating character `'\0'` is appended at the end of string literals.

Comment: At the end of a string there must be a special character that indicates the string is over. This character is `\0` and takes one byte, therefore the length of your array is 6, not 5.

Comment: Note that C will allow the array to be initialized without the trailing null, but C++ doesn't (a good thing in my opinion).

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442721/initializer-string-for-array-of-chars-is-too-long-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's a null character at the end, so the size should be `6`.

See [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes):

> The null character (`'\0'`, `L'\0'`, `char16_t()`, etc) is always appended
>   to the string literal: thus, a string literal `"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` 
>   holding the characters `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.

And when [initialize character arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization),

> If the number of initializer clauses exceeds the number of members and bases (since C++17) to initialize, the program is ill-formed (compiler error)

So compile failed.

And you don't need to specify the size at all, just `char name[] = "ABCDE";` will help you to avoid such kind of troubles.

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

strings in C are null-terminated.
What it means?

It means that they need an extra character to store the null character to indicate the end of the string.

Imagine a function parsing the "ABCDEF", how it knows when the string ended and don't invade other parts of the memory?
A: It knows just because the null character '\0'

So that's the reason you need to declare it with 1 extra character in mind.

To exemplify, imagine the piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char name[5] = "ABCDE";
        char test[] = "ANYTHING";
        printf("Hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

What you think it's gonna print? "ABCDE", right?

Actual output:

> Hello, ABCDEANYTHING

It happens because printf tries to find the end of the string (the first null character) but only find it when it's already iterating over the *test* variable in a improper memory access.

It's a "good scenario", in the worst case your program will crash with a buffer overflow and could leave area for security exploitation.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler implicitly terminates string literals with the null `\0` termination character. So, every string literal you declare actually has an extra `\0` character to the end.

```
char name[6] = "ABCDE";   // <-- Actually [ABCDE\0]
char name[] = "ABCDE";   // <-- Compiler figures it out
```